# Single Linked List in C (pointers, delete first, why do I have to keep the data separately?)

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list

```
    boolean consume_first(struct list ** ptrptr, float * value){

    struct list * temp;
    if((*ptrptr) != NULL){
        *value = (*ptrptr)->data; //HERE
        temp = (*ptrptr);
        *ptrptr = (*ptrptr)->next;
        free(temp); //and HERE

        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**HERE** (in the code)

Once I use "free" the data would also wipe, or not?

The "program" is not made to be functional, I called and passed arguments with the only purpose on "implementing" it later.

MAIN AND OTHER STUFF:

```
struct list{
    float data;
    struct list * next;
};

void init(struct list**);
void visit(struct list*);
int get_value(float*);
void pre_insert(struct list**, float*);
boolean consume_first(struct list**, float*); //HERE
void suf_insert(struct list **, float*);

int main(){

    struct list * listA;
    struct list * listB;

    init(&listA);
    init(&listB);

    float * data = NULL;
    *data = get_value(data);

    pre_insert(&listA, data);
    pre_insert(&listB, data);

    visit(listA);
    visit(listB);

    consume_first(&listA, &listA->data); //HERE
    consume_first(&listB, &listB->data); //HERE

    suf_insert(&listA, data);
    suf_insert(&listB, data);



    return 0;
}
```

*(sorry for bad English, I did my best)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 free(temp);
```

As `temp` points to `*ptrptr`, therefore, above will free the memory allocated to `*ptrptr`. It will be incorrect to access data using `*ptrptr` after it is freed.

It will however not effect the data stored in `*value`.

```
*value = (*ptrptr)->data;
```

this comes before `free` statement and also data is being stored at memory location pointed by pointer `value`. It will remain valid and can be used.

*Also, pay attention to this* (maybe you are aware but)-

```
temp = (*ptrptr);
*ptrptr = (*ptrptr)->next;       // *ptrptr points to next pointer in list now
free(temp);
```

So, *you are not freeing pointer whose value is stored in* `value` but the next pointer in the list. As you make `*ptrptr` point to next pointer( or next node in the list).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really fast :)